# Catch one scroll

Tags: javascript, jquery, scroll, jquery-events, mousewheel

I use the `scrollTop` along with the mousewheel tweak on jQuery to navigate on my website, the problem is: it works (not so bad) with a real mouse : you have to scroll ONE notch to go to second part of the site if you scroll 2 notches it'll go to page 3 etc..

So when someone uses a laptop to scroll it seems very buggy: it goes straight to the last page of the site.

I'd like to know how to catch several notches of scrolls till the user stops scrolling. Exactly like on this page: neverbland.com

Here's mine: knmprod.com/knmprod

Comment: Isn't the concept of "notches" a little risky? I know I've seen many newer mousewheels that have almost continuous motion and really weakly defined notches.

Comment: Also, your description of how you want it to act doesn't seem to me like that's what neverbland.com is doing.  It seems to be beginning a single one-unit scroll immediately when I move the wheel. No matter how many notches I cover during the time it takes to scroll, I end up at the same destination. I have to move the wheel again after the next slide is displayed in order to initiate a scroll to the next slide.  FWIW, Chrome 21.0.1180.83 on Windows 7 here.

Comment: Every time you blatantly steal a design, a cute kitten dies. Just sayin'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the [mousewheel plugin](http://brandonaaron.net/code/mousewheel/docs) and a timer to check for when the wheel hasn't moved for several milliseconds – say 250 – and then execute the  page change. This will allow a single page change for each mouse movement, regardless of the speed or type of mouse – same as neverbland.com does:

```
$('body').mousewheel(function() {
  clearTimeout($(this).data('timer'));
  $(this).data('timer', setTimeout(function() {
     alert('Change Page');
  }, 250));
});
```

[JSFiddle Here](http://jsfiddle.net/QJSz4/2/)

I hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Set a timer every time you get a mousewheel event, every time you get another event cancel the first one.

Only once you stop getting events for some amount of time (say .5 second) then trigger your action.

```
var timer, longTimer = false, delta;

$('.page').bind('mousewheel', function(e, localDelta) {
  if(!longTimer) longTimer = setInterval(action, 1500);
  clearInterval(timer);
  timer = setInterval(action, 500);
  delta = localDelta;
}

function action() {
  clearInterval(timer);
  clearInterval(longTimer);
  longTimer = false;

  if(delta<0) {
    number=plusone(number);
    goToByScroll(number);
  } else {
    number= minusone(number);
    goToByScroll(number);
  } 
}
```

Comment: What is "your action" here? Beginning the scroll?

Comment: @ChrisFarmer The action is moving to the next page. i.e. only do that once the wheel stops - but it doesn't matter how far it traveled before doing so - this solves the problem you mentioned about notches. There should probably be a second trigger that if the wheel scrolls continuously for more than 1.5 second, trigger an action anyway. It would be clearer in code probably.

Comment: jQuery(function($) {
    $('.page').bind('mousewheel', function(event, delta) {
     if(delta<0){
   number=plusone(number);
   goToByScroll(number);    
   
  }
  else{

   number= minusone(number);
   goToByScroll(number);
    

  }
    });

});

Comment: I guess I understand your logic, but waiting half a second to begin to scroll seems a long wait, especially since the act of scrolling in his examples also takes about half a second.

Comment: @ChrisFarmer I'm assuming he would tune the timer after implementing it so see what gives the best feel. I've posted the code above.

Comment: @YassBen Scrolling is on you - edit the action function if I got it wrong. Put an alert in that function so you can be sure it's getting triggered.

Comment: @Ariel ok I got the scrolling workin, but it still does scroll to the end of the page ..

Answer (score 0):

Does this not work?

```
​$(window).scroll(function(){alert(1)});​
```

http://jsfiddle.net/2hwu9/

Comment: So you would animate your page 3 times.